# error on response redirect in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am redirecting api url to REST api url. Code is as below

```
app.use('/api/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept");
    console.log("Inside API", req.url);
    res.redirect(http://myrestapi/'+req.url);
});
```

While post request of http://localhost:3000/api/login getting below error

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
Please suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: The browser response from your REST API url will need to have all the proper CORS headers on it.  Otherwise, the browser will not allow the result from the API server.  It's the server that is serving the request (the one you are redirecting to), not the one that is redirecting from that needs the proper CORS headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is overriding header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".

try this one,

```
app.use("/api/*",function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  console.log("Inside API", req.url);
  res.redirect("http://myrestapi/"+req.url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't recreate your issue. But if you want to enable *all* CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) requests you can simply put `app.use(cors());` at the top of your file.